# Adding JSF 2.2 results in "Found multiple versions of the required class javax.faces.FactoryFinder"

Tags: eclipse, jsf

I'm wondering how I can use JSF 2.2 (instead of the 2.0.2) in Eclipse?

It seems like there is no official release (only majorra 2.0 and myfaces 2.0.2 are available)
and when I add jsf 2.2 impl and api manually (Project Facets), it tells me: "**Found multiple versions of the required class javax.faces.FactoryFinder.**". 
When i remove the old (myfaces 2.0.2) tomcat fails...

is there a way to make JSF 2.2 run in eclipse as default?

Comment: It's the same way as with JSF 2.1, 2.0, 1.2, 1.1 and 1.0. "Multiple versions" just means that you mixed Mojarra (jsf-impl.jar) with MyFaces (myfaces-impl.jar). You would have had exactly the same problem when doing so with other versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can both, add the library to your classpath or configure it in jsf preferences, if you've the facet enabled. In the first way you're not telling Eclipse you're using JSF and second way you tell it and you can choose between configuring the classpath yourself or make Eclipse choose which JSF jars you want to use to let it include them.

First of all you need to download the jars from [Mojarra's](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html) or [MyFaces'es](http://myfaces.apache.org/download.html) site. MyFaces doesn't have 2.2 version implemented as of today.

To just add the library to your classpath, right click on the project and go to *Properties, Java build path*. Then click on *Add JAR* or *Add External JARs*, depending where you have the jar and add the jsf-api and jsf-impl jars.

[image]

Otherwise, if you have the project configured as a JSF project, firstly you have to enable the JSF facet, check *Project Facets*. Then Eclipse will create a submenu inside *Project Facets*, letting you configure JSF. You can choose *disable library configuration* and do it the previous way or select *User Library*:

[image]

Then click on the books icon and you can add a new user library. Once added you only need to add required jars. Keep in mind that you need both jsf-api and jsf-impl jars to have it working, as Tomcat is a plain servlet container and doesn't include any JSF implementation out of the box.

Alternatively, you can also place the jsf-impl directly in your Tomcat shared libraries folder. You should drop it in [$CATALINA_HOME/lib](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) and every single application you deploy will use the same implementation. In that way you can just reference the jsf-api from your projects and code against it, having the implementation itself into the server's classpath.